# Can we validate pdf with WEBDRIVER.IO APIs?

Tags: webdriver-io

looking for below solution.any docs that can help
Can we validate pdf with WEBDRIVER.IO APIs ?
usecase - pdf will be download on mobile device in download section , need to read/validate the pdf with webdriver io
Any solutions ? thanks